# Problems installing MySQL Server 5.7.2 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mysql

Apparently when you install MySQL Server 5.7, a window is supposed to appear showing a temporary password for the root account. This window never appeared, and it won't let me log into mysql as root without a password. I am having trouble going through the steps to reset the root password.

I tried to reset the root password by starting mysql like this:

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

but then it still won't let me log in as root without a password. Also, System Preferences will immediately crash if I select MySQL from the preference pane. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 is not supported on Mountain Lion. You will need 5.6 or update your OS.

Source: MySQL.com - [Supported Platforms: MySQL Database](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html)

Mavericks 10.9 tends to be the base OS supported for modern structures.